# Using the GitHub API how can I find the card id that is linked to a specific issue without iterating through the cards in a project?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

The end result is I am trying to start with an issue number (tied to an issue card on a project) and programmatically move it to a different column.

I've found this endpoint [POST /projects/columns/cards/{card_id}/moves](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects#move-a-project-card) moves the card. This requires the ID of the card.

So I'm looking for a clean way to start with an issue number and get the card id for the card connected to that issue.

Each card object has the `content_url` field which seems to be what makes a card an "issue card", however there is no way shown in the documentation to try to search for a card with a specific content_id.

Of course, I can just request the [GET /projects/columns/{column_id}/cards](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects#list-project-cards) endpoint to get a list of all the cards in the column and iterate through until I find one that has a `content_id` that matches the url for the issue, but I'm wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [GitHub GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql).

```bash
query='query {
  repository(owner: "owner", name: "repo") {
    issue(number: 1234) {
      projectCards {
        nodes {
          databaseId
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

# you don't need to use GitHub CLI, curl is enough
gh api graphql -f query=$query
```